# What is wrong with this email headers? It always go to gmail and yahoo spam box

Tags: email, postfix, spam

```
Delivered-To: xxxx@gmail.com

Received: by 10.229.249.207 with SMTP id ml15cs152516qcb;
        Tue, 9 Aug 2011 05:22:45 -0700 (PDT)

Received: by 10.151.142.17 with SMTP id u17mr6831320ybn.198.1312892565452;
        Tue, 09 Aug 2011 05:22:45 -0700 (PDT)

Return-Path: <xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx>

Received: from mail.mydomain.com.br (mail.mydomain.com.br [xx.xx.xxx.xx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g4si5211294ybi.22.2011.08.09.05.22.44;
        Tue, 09 Aug 2011 05:22:44 -0700 (PDT)

Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx designates xx.xx.xxx.xx as permitted sender) client-ip=x.xx.xxx.xx;

Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx designates x.xx.xxx.xx as permitted sender) smtp.mail=xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx; dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com.br

Received: from mydomain.com.br (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [x.xx.xxx.xx])
    by mail.mydomain.com.br (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 02C12B543AE
    for <xxxx@gmail.com>; Tue,  9 Aug 2011 09:22:42 -0300 (BRT)

DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; s=mail; d=mydomain.com.br; c=simple; q=dns;
    b=K7lPw72zqmctULDiEdOjdgQWpmClkICAjdKo07hkSicyQU7nRjFAQXR9hf270t0aq
    wD5XjP35FRY3a52kNsVo1OAI22ttiKEDUC/N9e0/57cnoTXFVvzumYBSylgKyk3mPbu
    H0cEJtAVlutfgCES8x1Gdjigd/ek11WQabWWjnk=

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=mydomain.com.br;
    s=mailk; t=1312892562;
    bh=1lADbHhk2GRaz/mXB4uRhcq7+ei8fg20sFxDsiIDW4A=;
    h=Date:To:From:Reply-to:Subject:Message-ID:MIME-Version:
     Content-Type;
    b=NN2JnPJJZfWnAjYU8x1dC5Cwz3WbkwPAx1yU0w9Xbz55Aa2KpbpIYnTiRmbKg7L0O
     7aP0EgAoqCMRwni6S6HqLw3MjR2I3B3qVmkMkyKMHjZ6N2sivovrTq/R0P9A4X+8G9
     GLim31Yo/ZTLl3cEyOrWCvokAVJYMSm/uS8aTpaY=

Date: Tue, 9 Aug 2011 09:22:42 -0300

To: xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx

From: xxxxx <xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx>

Reply-to: xxxxx <xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx>

Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Reuni=E3o_de_professores_na_escola?=

Message-ID: <b8b16385ed9c0141365ee6257a39d284@xxxxx>

X-Priority: 3

X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_b8b16385ed9c0141365ee6257a39d284"


--b1_b8b16385ed9c0141365ee6257a39d284
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Teremos reunião na escola a noite, favor comparecer. obrigado.

--b1_b8b16385ed9c0141365ee6257a39d284
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<html>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#052444">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="510">
<tr>
<td>
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Teremos reunião na escola a noite, favor comparecer. obrigado.</a></b></font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

--b1_b8b16385ed9c0141365ee6257a39d284--
```

Mail always to Gmail and Yahoo always go to spam.

The server is dedicated and it's not blacklisted.

Perhaps it could be some postfix config?

Comment: Always a joy to reading obfuscated headers...

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly the fact that the body of the e-mail is very short, and the subject is gobbledygook to a English based spam filter.

```
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Reuni=E3o_de_professores_na_escola?=
```

Comment: +1 and the HTML body probably isn't helping either.

Comment: u mean that subject doesn't match with body contents?

Comment: @ubunpstfix, The subject contains 11 "non-normal" characters ("=", "?", and "_") that would cause my spam filters to go crazy; I imagine Google's filters are similar. I know it's an international encoding; but most spam filters aren't terribly smart.

Comment: And it is from Brazil. Probably on some blacklists. But without knowing the IP...

Comment: my dedicated server is not blacklisted, i already checked it.

Comment: @ubupstfix: it looks like a malformed query string.  And since you're using PHP xmailer, I'm assuming these are automated emails? I'd check the template/string concatenation; you're likely putting stuff in the subject you don't want to.

Comment: @Chris S, i turned off this subject encode. but it still go to spam box, Subject: Reunião de professores na escola

Comment: @ubunpstfix, at this point you're likely graylisted. So almost anything you send to GMail will end up in the junk folder for the next month. Also, just changing the Subject doesn't change the extremely short body length (and the HTML version is almost all HTML, very little content). These are all strikes against your e-mail.

Comment: @gravyface, i'm sending it via php using php mailer with smtp authentication, could it be the reason?

Comment: Could be a bunch of things, but you need to find out why your subject line looks malicious.

Comment: @Gravyface; it's valid/standard international encoding, just most spam filters don't recognize that.

Comment: @Chris S: looks malicious though, which is why the spam filters are picking it up.

Comment: @gravyface, I think I said that already, like in the Answer...

Comment: @Chris S: and I've already upvoted you, sooooo.... ?